# If Statement will not copy the results to a seperate page

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, copy-paste

Creating an If statement, to sort out my data based on the month in a certain column. The code is as such

```
Worksheets("Project Info").Activate

Dim month As Long
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For month = Cells(Rows.Count, 23).End(xlUp).Row To 1 Step -1
    If InStr(1, Cells(month, 23).Value Like "1/*", 1) _
    Then Cells(month, 23).EntireRow.Copy
    Worksheets("January").Activate
    ActiveSheet.Paste
Next month
```

For some reason, it won't copy data into the specified page. It doesn't even actually copy the data at all. Any ideas?

Comment: You should use sheet references throughout. Once you activate the January sheet your code will refer to that as it is the active sheet.

Comment: I've tried that, unfortunately to no avail.

Comment: @SFarrell But **how** did you try that? *"no avail"* doesn't help us to understand where your difficulties were. Please [edit] your question and update the code. As SJR pointed out the code cannot work as expected as shown in the question. The following might help: [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba).

Comment: I have updated it. I was using activate sheet any time I was changing sheets, to ensure the correct one was selected.

Comment: That change does not address my point. However, the answer might.

Comment: You are basically using the single line syntax.

Add `End If` at the end of your code block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments above, you need to use sheet references otherwise you are going to jump back and forth between sheets and after the first iteration you are copying and pasting to the same sheet.  You also have to specify where you are going to paste the data and change the destination each time, otherwise you will keep pasting over the same data.

```
Dim ws1 as Worksheet
Dim ws2 as Worksheet

Set ws1 = Worksheets("Project Info")
Set ws2 = Worksheets("January")

Dim month As Long
Dim t as Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

t=1
For month = ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, 23).End(xlUp).Row To 1 Step -1
    If InStr(1, ws1.Cells(month, 23).Value Like "1/*", 1) Then
       ws1.Cells(month, 23).EntireRow.Copy
       ws2.Rows(t).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
       t=t+1
    End if
Next month
```

Comment: Note this copies only if the `If` statement is true, but it pastes **always** because your `If` statement is a one-liner and has no `End If`. Which the OP probably meant to do.

Comment: Just another thing: `Month` is already a function in VBA ([Month function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/month-function)) and should therefore be forbidden (highly not recommended) as a variable name.